# How can I bind a member function to a std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I want to do an array of OIS::Keys (int) and of std::function.

I have this :

```
struct UserCommands
{
  OIS::KeyCode key;
  std::function<bool(Worms *, const Ogre::FrameEvent& evt)> func;
};

UserInput input;

UserCommands usrCommands[] =
{
  {
    OIS::KC_A, std::bind(&input, &UserInput::selectBazooka)
  },
};
```

But when I try to compile this I have this compile error :

```
    In file included from includes/WormsApp.hh:5:0,
                     /src/main.cpp:2:
/includes/InputListener.hh:26:25: error: could not convert ‘std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...) [with _Func = UserInput*; _BoundArgs = {bool (UserInput::*)(Worms*, const Ogre::FrameEvent&)}; typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type = std::_Bind<UserInput*(bool (UserInput::*)(Worms*, const Ogre::FrameEvent&))>](&UserInput::selectBazooka)’ from ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, UserInput*, bool (UserInput::*)(Worms*, const Ogre::FrameEvent&)>::type {aka std::_Bind<UserInput*(bool (UserInput::*)(Worms*, const Ogre::FrameEvent&))>}’ to ‘std::function<bool(Worms*, const Ogre::FrameEvent&)>’
         OIS::KC_A, std::bind(&input, &UserInput::selectBazooka)
                             ^
```

What have I done wrong ?

Comment: perhaps `std::bind(&UserInput::selectBazooka, &input, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)`

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a lambda? (imo it makes the code clearer than bind)

Comment: PiotrSkotnicki thansk that works fine !
@Borgleader How a lambda could be useful here ?

Comment: @DimitriDanilov Clarity mostly, in my opinion. See Walter's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument of `std::bind` is a callable object. In your case, that should be `&UserInput::selectBazooka`. The object to be associated with a call to that member function (`&input`) goes afterwards (you reversed this order). Still, you have to use placeholders for the missing parameters:

```
std::bind(&UserInput::selectBazooka, &input, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)
```

Answer (score 6):

Using a lambda, would be like this (instead of `std::bind()`)

```
[&](Worms*x, const Ogre::FrameEvent&y) { return input.selectBazooka(x,y); }
```